# Trouble creating a Doctrine ResultSetMapping for parsing a raw SQL query to a single database table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, concrete5

I am trying to convert a raw SQL command into Doctrine Entities. The sql command is:

```
        $sql = 'SELECT SUM(IF (SCORE = 1, 1, 0)) AS UPVOTE, SUM(IF (SCORE = -1, 1, 0)) AS DOWNVOTE, BLOCKID, ELEMENTID FROM Voting GROUP BY BLOCKID, ELEMENTID';
```

Which works and returns from the Voting table:

```
UPVOTE  DOWNVOTE  BLOCKID  ELEMENTID
1       1         3223     person1
3       2         3223     person2
0       1         3223     person3
```

I have the following PHP code in my controller file, which is currently returning an empty array:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT SUM(IF (SCORE = 1, 1, 0)) AS UPVOTE, SUM(IF (SCORE = -1, 1, 0)) AS DOWNVOTE, BLOCKID, ELEMENTID FROM Voting GROUP BY BLOCKID, ELEMENTID';
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('Concrete\Entity\Vote', 'u');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'blockid', 'blockid');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'elementId', 'elementId');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'score', 'score');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'ipAddress', 'ipAddress');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'created_at', 'created_at');

    $rsm->addScalarResult('upvote', 'upvote');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('downvote', 'downvote');

    $query = $this->em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);    
    $results = $query->getResult();
    echo json_encode($results);
```

I've tried consulting the Doctrine documentation but am having trouble ascertaining what my issue is. I have called addFieldResult on all the columns in my table (such as id, ipAddress, created_at) which don't appear at all in the results - is this required or not?

With the code above I get no errors, just an empty array being returned. Am I missing something or just plain doing this wrong?

Comment: You are not selecting any of the field expected by the `ResultSetMapping` you created in your SQL so it's not going to output anything. It would also be simpler if you used [`ResultSetMappingBuilder`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder) to add all the fields related to your `Vote` entity and generate the corresponding select clause as described in the doc (if that's what you want). Also, I think it might be case sensitive, so you should either use only `upvote` or `UPVOTE` for example but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a native query to execute this kind of query. You can rely on [`CASE` expressions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#case-expressions) to write your conditions. Using the query builder, your query would look like this:

```
$results = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('Concrete\Entity\Vote', 'v')
        ->select('v.elementId', 'v.blockId')
        ->addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN v.score = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upvote')
        ->addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN v.score = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downvote')
        ->groupBy('v.blockId')
        ->addGroupBy('v.elementId')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

---

In case you still want to use a native query, you don't need to over do it with your `ResultSetMapping` if you simply want to retrieve `BLOCKID` and `ELEMENTID` from your table. Simply use [`addScalarResult`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.ResultSetMapping.html#_addScalarResult) with the first argument being the name of the field/alias which appears in your `SELECT` clause and the second argument being the alias you want it to have in your result set. *(You can add a third argument to specify the type of the scalar value being retrieved as well, see `block_id` or `upvote` below).*

With a `Vote` entity like this one:

```
/** @ORM\Table(name="votes") */
class Vote
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="block_id", type="integer") */
    private $blockId;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="element_id", type="string") */
    private $elementId;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="score", type="integer") */
    private $score;
}
```

The following native query would output the same result as the query built with the query builder above.

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(IF (SCORE = 1, 1, 0)) AS upvote, SUM(IF (SCORE = -1, 1, 0)) AS downvote, block_id, element_id FROM votes GROUP BY block_id, element_id';
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('block_id', 'blockId', 'integer');
$rsm->addScalarResult('element_id', 'elementId');
$rsm->addScalarResult('upvote', 'upvote', 'integer');
$rsm->addScalarResult('downvote', 'downvote', 'integer');

$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);    
$result = $query->getResult();
```

*The only difference you will get is that the `upvote`/`downvote` values will be integers instead of strings since you could specify it here (while you couldn't with the query builder).*